# How do I parse Wikipedia XML dumps into one document per line?

Tags: xml, parsing, wikipedia, corpus

For a project, I need to convert a Wikipedia XML dump into a plain text corpus file which keeps one document per line. I have found several tools for splitting the XML dump into several different files, but this is not the needed format and I fear that managing millions of small files will add unnecessary work to my already slow HDD.

Any suggestions of good programs for this?

Comment: If your question is “I have a very specific problem, is there some program that does exactly what I want?” then the answer will most likely be “No”.

Comment: svick: Well, 'one document per line' is not an uncommon approach for corpora formatting, and considering the amount of programs I could find for 'one document per file' I thought there would be at least one such a program out there. Very well...

Comment: One sentence per line is more common, afaik, for plain text corpora.
If you have a working tool to parse into many small files, you can merge them, then remove all line feeds between <doc> tags, and you'd be done, maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use any streaming XML parser to read the dump page by page, strip line breaks from the page text and print it out.  If you told us what language(s) you're using, we might be able to offer more specific suggestions.

(If you're using Perl, I've seen many people recommend the XML::Twig module, but even plain old XML::Parser can do it just fine.)